# windows 8 shutdown process differs from Vista?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-8, shutdown

I have app that should do smth on shutdown, I mean - when user presses shutdown, app blocks shutdown, and does some stuff. We do it by handling WM_QUERYENDSESSION and WM_ENDSESSION. The job is done in WM_ENDSESSION handler. This works perfect in windows 7, XP.

The problem is as follows - on Windows 8 shutdown process gets cancelled after about 1 minute - shutdown UI is shown for some time, with my reason string, and then system goes to start screen. No shutdown, nothing happens. My app is still running.
At first I thought that the problem is in our app, but it **seems that system behaves in such way for all apps, not only for ours.** You can check it for yourself, just run some app, that you know, will block shutdown, and do the shutdown (or sign-off). You'll see shutdown UI, telling what apps are blocking shutdown. Just wait a little and after about 60-90 seconds it'll disappear - shutdown will get cancelled.

So I'm wondering whether MS changed something in shutdown process in Windows 8?

**Edit:** I can't post actual code here, so I'll post kinda pseudocode, to illustrate main points:

```
LRESULT CMainFrame::OnQueryEndSession(UINT, WPARAM , LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled) {
    m_bQueryEndSession = true;      
    bHandled = true;
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CMainFrame::OnEndSession(UINT, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled) {
    BOOL bEnding = (BOOL)wParam;

    if(!bEnding)
        return 0;

    if(m_bQueryEndSession && /*and some other checks*/ ) 
    {

        if (g_osver.dwMajorVersion >= 6) { 
            // of Vista and higher load User32.dll and call ShutdownBlockReasonCreate() here
        }

        {
            // all important job is done here
            // zzz
        }

        if (g_osver.dwMajorVersion >= 6) { 
            // of Vista and higher load User32.dll and call ShutdownBlockDestroy() here
        }
    }

    bHandled = true;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Vram you can use the new debugging process that is included in VS2012, see the link: [Debug features in VS 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/08/23/new-visual-studio-2012-debugging-features-for-the-windows-8-app-lifecycle-model.aspx).  Since the Windows 8 enforces states differently there may be a problem that these debugging tools may help you detect.  Hopefully this is not news to you.

It would be easier if you could post a code sample that demonstrates the problem you are debugging.

During my research, I also used this link, but might not be very useful: [WM_ENDSESSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376889%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for help man. But my app is not Windows store app. It's a good old desktop win32 app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, shutdown logic has been changed, but not in Windows 8.  It was changed way back in Vista, and the changes are documented on MSDN:

[Application Shutdown Changes in Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700677.aspx)

It is not enough to simply handle `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` and `WM_ENDSESSION` alone, there are new API functions involved to interact with the shutdown process.

Comment: I'm aware of changes in Vista and thoroughly read that article. I use ShutdownBlockReasonCreate and ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy, as specified in documentation (please see the code I've added). My question is about Windows 8 shutdown process - why its get cancelled after about one minute? Even when WM_QUERYENDSESSION handler haven't returned yet. As specified in that article - "Application can take as much time as needed to respond to WM_ENDSESSION. Windows displays new UI after 5 seconds." So I suppose they've changed something in that process - added some timeout or something.

Comment: The article says that apps who take more than 5-30 seconds to shutdown need to call `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()` in the `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` message handler, not in the `WM_ENDSESSION` handler like your pseudo code is doing.

Comment: tried to call ShutdownBlockReasonCreate in WM_QUERYENDSESSION handler - no use. Also tried returning true/false from that handler - also without success. Try it yourself - just start debugging some app with Visual Studio and then press sign-off. Result - shutdown will get cancelled after about 1 min.

Answer (score -1):

Also it seems that the custom string provided when calling `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()` does not get updated in Windows 8/8.1. It just displays the initial string, but no updates to it. I'm trying to let the user know why and how long I'm going to block the shutdown.